# Dropdownlist - вызывать iactionresult при каждом выборе элемента, а также получение выбранного значения

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, controller

Изучаю Asp.net core. Написал для теста простенький DropDownList и хочу чтобы при каждом выборе элемента вызывался IActionResult в контроллере (а лучше обычный отдельный метод), а также чтобы выбранное значение в Dropdownlist вернулось в контроллер, для дальнейшего мною использования.

Есть ли достаточно простой способ это сделать?

Для последнего по идее нужен ViewModel, но без вызова методов в контроллере - это значение собственно никак не получить.

Контроллер

```
public class AddReqController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<UserM> users = new List<UserM>
        {
            new UserM {Id=1, Name="Tom", Age=35 },
            new UserM {Id=2, Name="Alice", Age=29 },
            new UserM {Id=3, Name="Sam", Age=36 },
            new UserM {Id=4, Name="Bob", Age=31 },
        };
        List<CargoObject> getpers = _context.DBCargo.ToList();

        ViewBag.UserM = new SelectList(getpers, "ID", "Name");
        return View();
    }
}
```

```
public class UserM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("userid", ViewBag.Users as SelectList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, в контроллере есть метод:

```
public string CallFromDropDown(string value)
{
    return value + " !";
}
```

Он принимает один параметр строку и возвращает эту же строку с добавленным восклицательным знаком.

Добавим к дропдауну подписку на событие `onchange`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("userid", ViewBag.Users as SelectList,
   new { @onchange = "selectChanged(this.value)" })
```

Функция `selectChanged` отправляет get-запрос в описанный ранее метод и получает результат, который показывается в окошке `alert`.

```
function selectChanged(value) {        
    fetch(`AddReq/CallFromDropDown?value=${value}`)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => alert(data))
        .catch(error => alert(error))
}
```

Вам остаётся описать нужную логику в контроллере и логику обработки возвращённых данных.