# Как из js файла передать данные в метод контроллера? MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Имеется MVC проект. Нужно с js передать данные в метод контроллера.

Допустим, есть объект в js

```
class Counter {
    count = 0;
}
```

Как из него вытащить count и передать на бэк?

UPD - подробное описание.

Есть три `счетчика`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `js` это три объекта, со своим набором функций.
Мне требуется достать значение каждого объекта и передать в метод контроллера, чтобы дальше как-то обработать эти данные.

Пример объекта счетчика

```
class Counter {
    count = 0;
    constructor(increase, decrease, output) {
        this.increase = increase;
        this.decrease = decrease;
        this.output = output;
     }

     //функция инкремента
     this.increase.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.output.innerHTML = ++this.count;
     });

}
```

Вот сюда должны попасть значения

```
public IActionResult SomeMethod(string values) {..}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, конкретизируйте вопрос, что вы имеете в виду под словом бэк

Comment: @SpaceResearcher я, видимо, перемудрил немного. Есть монолитное приложение, у него в файле js есть какие-то данные. Надо из этого файла передать данные в метод контроллера.

Comment: @dasper Ваше монолитное приложение уже умеет передавать данные в сторонние API?

Comment: На бэке должен быть некий метод по некоему адресу. Из js посылаем запрос на этот адрес. [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1287736/184217), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009632/184217)

Comment: @SwaD это небольшое приложение, тут нет необходимости передавать данные другим API

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо! попробую на досуге

Comment: код свой добавьте в вопрос, непонятно что вам на самом деле нужно

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak добавил.

Comment: Откройте практически любой туториал по asp.net на сайте Microsoft и там будет про взаимодействие фронта и бэка.